# ARIMA with increasing variance

Tags: variance, arima, data-transformation

my time series data looks like that:[image]

I would like to use ARIMA model to forecast next steps in time series. Unfortunately because of increasing variance data is non-stationary. 
Is there any way to transform my data to get rid of this variance? 
In addition before training I normalised data. Is normalisation required by ARIMA model?

Comment: Try a variance stabilizing transform, like the log.

Comment: What  demetri said is fine. You could also try to model the process directly by saying possibly $y_t = \mu + \epsilon_t$ where the variance of  $\epsilon$ is say  (arch or garch ) or stochastic ( so SV model ). Just another possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Demetrios says](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390099/arima-with-increasing-variance#comment732503_390099), you could try transforming your data to stabilize the variance. The classical approach is to use a [Box-Cox transformation](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html). One special case of this is the log transform. Some software will estimate a Box-Cox transformation parameter $\lambda$ for you.

Alternatively, as [mlofton says](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390099/arima-with-increasing-variance#comment732508_390099), you could consider modeling your variance directly using an ARCH or a GARCH model. Your data does look somewhat like a financial returns series to me, with an essentially constant mean. In finance, we are often most interested in modeling variances, not so much means, and ARCH/GARCH is custom-made for this.

Comment: in fact this is financial data. Thanks for great tip!